# Getting Trouble in Dismissing Ads from Website using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to do web automation where I am using selenium library to moves towards one page for finding title of that page but when I am trying to click on find button suddenly ads pop up and it disturbs the flow and it will not allow the find button to click on it. Let me know that how can I close that ad so that I can move towards the next page and get the tile of that page.

Here is my code:

```
#Using Selenium to move towards the next pages by clicking on button

#Libs Included 
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

#Path to Chrome Driver 
path='chromedriver.exe'    
driver=webdriver.Chrome(path)
    
#Main_Url Page
main_url='https://www.zameen.com/'

#Getting the MainPage
driver.get(main_url)
print(driver.title)


#Selecting the Drop Down Menu First 
search=driver.find_element_by_class_name('eedc221b').click()


#How To Move to  Specific Area using  Finding Box To get All the List of Cities
list_of_cities=[]
Cities=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("d92d11c7")
#print(Cities)
for i in Cities:
    city=i.text
    list_of_cities.append(city)
#print("List of Cities are:  \n",list_of_cities)
    
#Reach towards the first Location by sending the citname to the combobox and then hit enter 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[aria-label='"+Cities[0].text+"']").click()

time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[aria-label='Find button'][class='c3901770 _22dc5e0a']").click()

    
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,"html")))
    print("Tilte of next Page is: {0}".format(driver.title))
    time.sleep(5)  
    driver.quit()


finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That add close button can be identified with the help of below `css selector`  :

```
# Path to Chrome Driver 
path = 'chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
# Main_Url Page
main_url = 'https://www.zameen.com/'
driver.maximize_window()
# Getting the MainPage
driver.get(main_url)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.close_cross_big"))).click()
except:
    print("could not click")
    pass
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

and then you can continue with the rest of your code.

Comment: Kindly let me where these lines to be added in my script

Comment: @AbdulRehman : Check the updated code above, I have tried to replicate the same with your code.